# Using a shared variable between routes and main in flask

Tags: python, flask, shared-variable

I have a python flask server. In the `main` of my script, I get a variable from user that defines the mode of my server. I want to set this variable in `main` (just *write*) and use it (just *read*) in my controllers. I am currently using `os.environ`, but I 'm searching for more flasky way to use.

I googled and tried following options:

1. `flask.g`: it is being reset for each request; so, I can't use it inside controllers when it is being set somewhere else.
2. `flask.session`: it is not accessible outside request context and I can't set it in the main.
3. `Flask-Session`: like the second item, I  can't set it in the `main`.

Comment: maybe you should save it in file or in database.

Comment: Yes @furas, you are correct. But I'm searching for a way to do it by `flask` methods and objects if possible.

Comment: as for me `flask/django/PHP` method is to keep data in database. If `main` doesn't have access to `flask` then database or file can be solution. But now I'm wondering  what if you set `app.variable = value` or how flask use `app.config`

Comment: I will try your suggestions @furas and let you know of the results. Thanks.

Comment: Dear @furas, both `app.config["mode"]` and `app.mode` worked. Would you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main` you use `app.run()` so `app` is avaliable in `main`. It should be also avaliable  all time in all functions so you can try to use

```
app.variable = value
```

but flask has also

```
app.config
```

to keep any settings. See doc: [Configuration Handling](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/)